# Does the App Store update Java, if installed?

Tags: mac-appstore, java

If I installed Java (or an older version), will the App Store update my local installation, even though I installed, and updated it outside of that?

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: Where and how did you install Java6?

Comment: @klanomath I installed Java6 in the default path, supplied from the link (apple) above.  No other version of Sun Java is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Java6 provided by Apple should be updated by the App Store, given any newer versions will be released (which i doubt).

(Tested with `Mavericks` & `Apple Java RE 1.6.0_51` in a VM. It was updated to `Apple Java RE 1.6.0_65` by `App Store`)

Java7 & Java8 provided by Oracle use their own update services.